# C++ Declare same thread variable multiple times (in a loop)

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I was wondering what will happen if I do something like this:

```cpp
void afunction(/*parameters*/) { /*do something*/ }

// And then in main... 

while(1) {
    thread aThread(afunction, /*parameters*/);
    athread.detatch();
    sleep(1);
}
```

Does this create an infinite amount of threads (until the system crashes)? Or does it overwrite the old thread after 1 second (like killing the thread and create a new one)? Are there any problems I have to worry about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The former.

In particular, when control enters the while-loop-body's scope, the  `thread` object `aThread` is created and a new OS-thread is spawned by its constructor (note I'm assuming here that you are using `std::thread` and not some other thread class).

Then you call `detach()` on the thread-object, so the OS-thread is no longer associated with the `aThread` object, but it is still running.

Then after a one-second delay, the end of the scope is reached, so the `aThread` object is destroyed, but since the OS-thread was detached from the `aThread` object, the OS-thread is left to continue running on its own.

Then the scope is entered again for the next iteration of the while-loop, and the whole process repeats, indefinitely.

In general, it's better to call `join()` on your threads rather than `detach()`, since that will allow your program to do a well-ordered shutdown.  Without `join()`, it's difficult or impossible to tear down process-wide resources safely, since you can't guarantee that the still-running threads might not be in the middle of using those resources at the time the tear-down occurs.  Therefore, most well-written multi-threaded programs will call `join()` on all currently running threads, just before the end of `main()`, if not earlier.

Comment: Note that when using `std::thread`, a detached OS thread will clean itself up when it stops running so it won't take up OS resources needlessly. An un-detached OS thread won't be cleaned up until `std::thread::join()` is called. If the OS thread stops running before `join()` is called, the thread will just sit idle taking up OS resources.

Comment: Thanks! As following question - in my Application, I want to run an endless loop inside the thread, therefore I'm unable to use `std::thread::join()`, but if all is working fine, this is not a problem for me. Now - if I start a `std::thread`, don't call `std::thread::join()`and also don't call `std::thread::detach()`, my Application terminates with an error at the end. But what happens, when my Application crashes midway in execution? Does the thread also get destroyed?

Comment: If your application crashes, all of its threads will be killed by the OS (regardless of whether you called `detach()` on them or not), and all memory and resources freed up.  (not that you should allow your application to ever crash anyway :) )

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot :)